# Error with getPost function

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with the getPost function of the rfacebook package when connecting to certain commercial facebook pages such as The North Face.

I constructed the following steps to get the post data from The North Face:

```
#Step1
#start the libaries
library(Rfacebook)
library(Rook)
library(igraph)

#step 2
#browse an set token
browseURL("https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer")

token <- "...insert access token from facebook..."

#step 3
#choose facebook page of The North Face and get 1000 posts
page.thenorthface <- getPage("thenorthface", token, n=1000)
View(page.thenorthface)

#step 4
#get post information
post.thenorthface <- getPost("...insert random post id from page.thenorthface...", token, n = 500, comments = TRUE,likes = TRUE, n.likes=500, n.comments=500)
View(post.thenorthface)
```

The error occurs in the last step. In german it says:

```
Fehler in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  Failed connect to :80; Connection refused
```

Meaning: "Error in function (type, msg, ..."

I did not find any information about this problem but was able to reproduce it on other (OSX) computers.

The error does not occur with some other/smaller companies such as "WengerSA".

Does anybody have an idea? Maybe facebook is blocking the access to information on certain commercial pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need R 3.0.3. It's not working with 3.0.2. Simple as that...